# What does integrating position yield?

Tags: integration

What does taking the integral of x(t) yield? I'm very inquisitive and far ahead of my school math, but i have yet to understand what the result is.

Comment: Do you mean $ ∫ x(t) dt $ , where $ x(t)$ denotes time varying position ?

Comment: Honestly -- it is meaningless. In physics, of course. Try Googling it. Have you considered a much more interesting question -- what is the derivative of acceleration? It actually has a physical meaning.

Answer (score 3):

It yields many many many many many many things.

One of them is the average value. If you want to know how big $x(t)$ is on average for $t$ between $t=a$ and $t=b$, find the integral of $x(t)$ from $t=a$ to $t=b$, and divide by $b-a$.